ML.NET pipeline for predict vector
I have this error:
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Schema mismatch for label column 'Label': 
expected Single, got Vector\<Single\> Arg_ParamName_Name'

on line :
var model = pipeline.Fit(trainingData);

Whole method:
    public void Train(List<PolygonInput> data, string modelPath)
    {
        var trainingDataView = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(data);

        var trainTestData = mlContext.Data.TrainTestSplit(trainingDataView, testFraction: 0.2);
        var trainingData = trainTestData.TrainSet;
        var testData = trainTestData.TestSet;

        var pipeline = mlContext.Transforms.Concatenate("Features", nameof(PolygonInput.Features))
            .Append(mlContext.Regression.Trainers.LightGbm(new LightGbmRegressionTrainer.Options
            {
                LabelColumnName = "Label",
                FeatureColumnName = "Features"
            }));

        var model = pipeline.Fit(trainingData);

        mlContext.Model.Save(model, trainingData.Schema, modelPath);

        var predictions = model.Transform(testData);
        var metrics = mlContext.Regression.Evaluate(predictions, labelColumnName: "Label");

        Console.WriteLine($"R-Squared: {metrics.RSquared}, MAE: {metrics.MeanAbsoluteError}");
    }



public class PolygonInput
{
    [LoadColumn(0, 15)]
    [VectorType(16)]
    public float[] Features { get; set; }

    [LoadColumn(16, 17)]
    [VectorType(2)]
    public float[] Label { get; set; } 
}

Im trying to build model for predicting vector of 2 values (x,y).
Is it possible to build model which gonna predict me vector of values?
